# graphing values from a dict in plotly and eliminating zero values

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to figure out how to remove the zero values from the x axis of my bar graph. I am trying to graph the frequency of different products gained by multiplying the results of rolling three dice. I have created two lists, one of the frequencies and one of the total number of values including ones that do not come up. I joined those lists to create a dictionary and then removed the pairs where the value was 0. then i split the modified dict into two lists. When i print the x and y values, they are correct in the interpreter but the graph shows that all the products with zero values.

```
results = []

for roll_num in range(1000):
    result =die_1.roll() * die_2.roll() * die_3.roll()
    results.append(result)

#analyze the results
frequencies = []
max_result = die_1.num_sides * die_2.num_sides * die_3.num_sides
for value in range(2, max_result+1):
    frequency = results.count(value)
    frequencies.append(frequency)


#visualize the results
x_values =list(range(1, max_result+1))

frequency_dictionary = dict(zip(x_values, frequencies))
frequency_dictionary_fixed = {x:y for x,y in frequency_dictionary.items() if y!=0}

x_axis_plot, y_axis_plot = zip(*frequency_dictionary_fixed.items())

frequencies_fixed = list(filter(lambda num: num != 0, frequencies))

data = Bar(x=x_axis_plot, y=y_axis_plot)

x_axis_config = {'title': 'Results', 'dtick': 1}
y_axis_config = {'title': 'Frequency of Results'}
my_layout = Layout(title= "Result of rolling two D6 1000000 times",
    xaxis = x_axis_config, yaxis = y_axis_config)

offline.plot({'data': data, 'layout': my_layout}, filename = 'd6_d6.html')
print(x_axis_plot)
print(y_axis_plot)
```

(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 26, 27, 29, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 41, 43, 44, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 54, 55, 56, 59, 62, 63, 64, 65, 67, 69, 71, 74, 75, 76, 77, 79, 83, 84, 87, 89, 94, 95, 99, 101, 103, 104, 107, 109, 111, 113, 116, 118, 119, 124, 125, 127, 129, 131, 132, 135, 139, 143, 146, 149, 151, 152, 155, 159, 161, 164, 167, 169, 170, 174, 175, 179, 181, 188, 189, 191, 194, 195, 197, 199, 203, 207, 209, 215, 219, 223, 224, 227, 230, 233, 237, 239, 249, 251, 254, 255, 263, 265, 269, 271, 274, 279, 284, 287, 293, 299, 303, 305, 307, 311, 314, 319, 323, 329, 335, 339, 341, 349, 351, 356, 359, 374, 377, 379, 383, 389, 391, 398, 399, 407, 415, 419, 424, 431, 439, 449, 455, 461, 467, 474, 475, 479, 489, 499, 503, 519, 524, 527, 539, 543, 559, 569, 575, 594, 599, 607, 623, 629, 639, 647, 664, 679, 699, 713, 719, 755, 759, 815, 911)
(7, 5, 2, 5, 12, 1, 9, 2, 12, 1, 17, 2, 9, 15, 2, 13, 1, 15, 2, 3, 19, 3, 7, 15, 13, 4, 4, 5, 13, 2, 5, 18, 13, 1, 7, 27, 1, 5, 3, 7, 4, 1, 10, 3, 23, 3, 5, 3, 7, 2, 9, 26, 6, 2, 1, 4, 12, 14, 2, 1, 12, 2, 20, 6, 1, 3, 6, 10, 2, 11, 1, 3, 1, 24, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 3, 6, 18, 2, 7, 1, 1, 3, 9, 2, 1, 10, 1, 2, 2, 4, 19, 2, 2, 1, 14, 1, 1, 2, 6, 4, 2, 12, 7, 3, 7, 1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 21, 2, 7, 1, 3, 6, 3, 4, 3, 1, 8, 4, 10, 1, 6, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 8, 2, 2, 6, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 8, 1, 4, 3, 8, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 7, 2, 5, 1, 5, 6, 1, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2)

I want the x axis to only contain the values in the list above but when i graph it with plotly, it puts in all the zeros. Is there a way plot the graph while removing the zeros? [messy graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzNGm.png)

Comment: Please add imports to your code.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve).  In particular `die_n` is not defined and it will be great to know what kind of plot you are trying to achieve. It looks to me that using `pandas` could be of great help here.